# 'Title' is not getting inserted

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net, sql-server-2008, insert

I recently changed my site to allow a user to choose from a dropdown list or a textbox to be able to insert a title. The table is called Picklist, the columns are PicklistID, Title, Data.
Can someone help me with the insert of the title?

```
Protected Sub SubmitLink_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles SubmitLink.Click
  LinkModal.Hide()

  Dim strSQL As String = "INSERT INTO Picklist (Title, Data) VALUES (@Title, 
  @Data);INSERT INTO Marketing (ProductID, MarketingTypeID, MarketingTitle, 
  MarketingData) VALUES (@ProductID, 1, 'Link', scope_identity())"

    Using cn As New
    SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings
    ("LocalSqlServer").ConnectionString)

    Using cmd As New SqlCommand(strSQL, cn)
     If ddlDescription.SelectedValue <> "Select below or enter new" Then
       cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Title", ddlLink.SelectedValue))
     Else
       cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Title", NewLinkTitle.Text))
     End If
       cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Data", LinkURL.Text))
       cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@ProductID", ProductID.Value))

       cn.Open()

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

    End Using
    End Using
    Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl)
End Sub
```

Here are the dropdown and textbox:

```
Title:<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlLink" runat="server" DataSourceID="dsNewLink"
DataTextField="Title" DataValueField="Title" enableViewstate="False" 
AppendDataBoundItems="True">
   <asp:ListItem Text="Select below or enter new" Selected="True">
   </asp:ListItem>
      </asp:DropDownList><br />
New Title:<asp:TextBox ID="NewLinkTitle" runat="server">
          </asp:TextBox><br />
```

In the image below: See how in the background the line at the very top has nothing in it, but the delete button is there? That is a link that I just tried to add......the @Data column is inserted into the database, but not the @Title. But there are no errors! :/
[image]

Comment: Sure looks like it's adding a title... What, exactly, are you having trouble with?  Is there an error message?  If so, what is it?

Comment: No errors at all, but the title is not going into the database. The PicklistID and the Data columns are being inserted, but the Title field is blank. I will take a screenshot.

Comment: @jlg: a better idea would be to simply set a break point in your code on that IF statement to see what value the code thinks it is trying to put into the table... and debug from there.

Comment: @ChrisLively I'm not sure if I am debugging correctly. I just set the breakpoint and hit debug right? It just says waiting for localhost when I try to insert a new link.

Comment: @jlg: At that point, Visual Studio should have stopped the app and you should be able to look in your code window and go from there...

Comment: @ChrisLively The breakpoint turns yellow but I thought Visual Studio was supposed to tell me something when it turns the line yellow. It's not saying anything

Comment: @jlg: yellow simply means the program has properly stopped at that break point...  From there you can hover over the properties to see the contents.  Look at the Debug drop down menu to see your other options.  The main ones to use are Step Over (F10), Step Into (F11), and Continue (F5).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Things to do:

1. Check the column definition of your picklist table.  Is the Title column either a char or varchar and does it contain enough space to hold your inserted data?
2. Set a break point in your code on the IF statement and run the program.  When it gets there, inspect the ddlLink.SelectedValue property to see what, exactly, is contained there in.  Step through the app to see which branch of code it goes through.  And, finally, inspect the cmd.parameters property to see what values the parameters were set to.
3. If the above doesn't point out whats going on, use SQL Profiler and watch the query come across the wire.  Look at the query to see if it's passing everything you think it should.  If so, then copy that query and run it directly in management studio to find out what's going on.

Comment: It is passing the ddlLink.SelectedValue and inserting the value from the NewLinkTitle.Text. Even though I chose from the dropdown list, it only sees the textbox. Do you know how I can fix this?

Comment: The dropdown list worked to insert values before we added the textbox, just so you know. How did I screw that up with the textbox?

Comment: @jlg: sounds to me like you have something going on in your page_load method that is resetting the dropdown list selected item.  Show that code in your question.

Comment: I figured it out. Somewhere along the lines I copied and pasted one word that should've gone into a different Protected Sub, not this one. Copy and paste is not always your friend..... but thanks for the help. I always forget about breakpoints and will have to remember to use them more often!